# Intermittent Socket Exceptions calling API / Services from ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC site hosted in Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, .net-5

Error message in Application Insights:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (OurApiUrlAddress:443) A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

It's always a 21 seconds TCP timeout, this is a very generic error I know, but the reason for this error is not always the same, I've been reading all the threads about this. We've been investigating this problem for months with no luck, we're also in contact with Azure team.

**Important**: this same site written in RUBY was using this same API without any problem in the past, the API is responsive and it's called from other sites without any problem, but this specific site was migrated from RUBY to .NET and at the same time this site was hosted in AZURE, this are the 2 big changes. This just happens when the site (remember it's hosted in Azure) calls to API / services hosted in our company, this doesn't happen when site calls a service hosted somewhere else,  these makes us think the problem may be related to the company infrastructure but it can't be that alone, this has to be related to .NET and AZURE someway since these APIs and services respond perfectly to calls from other sites hosted in our network and they were working fine with the ruby version of this site. These Apis and services are not throwing this error when called in-browser from outside the company network.

The services/apis are behind a firewall but ports are perfectly configured (there are not any other traffic apps nor devices at play).

This error **doesn't** seem to be related to port exhaustion or SNAT, since sometimes only 1 developer alone is working in the DEV environment and he gets this socket exception error.

Just to give an idea we're getting around 250 socket exceptions a day on production, and this is just a small percentage of all the calls, so there is something that, just sometimes, is making this happen.

We know about the well known HttpClient issue when multiple instances are created, so we decided to use the Singleton approach ensuring only 1 instance per API/Service, as I'll show here, this is the call that gives more socket exceptions:

In `StartUp` class/file:

```
services.AddSingleton<IUploadApi>(new UploadApi(new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(appSettings.Endpoints.UploadServicesUrl) }));
```

Part of `appsettings.json`:

```
"Endpoints": {
    "UploadServicesUrl": "https://ourApiUrlAddress"
},
```

**UploadApi.cs**

```
public interface IUploadApi
{
    Task<UploadArtworkViewModel.UploadConfigurationData> GetUploadConfiguration();
}

public class UploadApi : IUploadApi
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public UploadApi(HttpClient client)
    {
        httpClient = client;
    }

    public async Task<UploadArtworkViewModel.UploadConfigurationData> GetUploadConfiguration()
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/GetUploadConfiguration").ConfigureAwait(false);
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UploadArtworkViewModel.UploadConfigurationData>(json);
    }
}
```

Call from controller:

```
model.UploadConfiguration = await UploadApi.GetUploadConfiguration().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

[image]

Any idea on things to test or places to look are welcome, obviously I've not been able to reproduce this one. We know there's always a 21 seconds timeout, that's a TCP timeout, but that doesn't help much. Maybe for some reason the connection is dropped or Azure is having problems (sometimes) when accessing the company network. I can post more info from application insights if needed but I don't see anything special there about the error.

**EDIT** - More info: It happens when any API or service is called from this MVC site Controllers, so the problem appears sporadically (still like 300 times per day) when the site server tries to reach an API or service, this makes me believe it's something related to the company infraestructure, but still no idea what it could be.

Comment: You could try using HttpClientFactory instead of the HttpClient Singleton. Small chance but at least it would recycle the instance every so often.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Ok, I have my code ready to test this, this would also allow an easy implementation of retry policies. I see if I can test this tomorrow on prod. I'll hope I have info about results tomorrow.

Comment: I've been told this method was used before with the same results, it was eventually changed to singleton method  because it had better results with Timeouts :(

Comment: Just to confirm HttpClientFactory approach had already been tested and the same happens, we get socket exceptions. About the retry policies, we are trying to fix the socket exception problem now, so we wont be adding retries to "hide" it for now.

Comment: is your app service plan windows?

Comment: Hello, what solution was implemented. Azure on premise gateway, vpn, other?

Comment: Yes it's Windows Plan, Premium v2 Service Plan, P3v2 Instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally got this problem fixed after working together with Azure team for some time, it was a gateway problem, solution was applying NAT/Vnet Integration. This is what we did to fix it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/nat-gateway-integration

Answer (score 0):

From asp.net monsters:

[image: TCP Connection diagram - Source: https://www4.cs.fau.de/Projects/JX/Projects/TCP/tcpstate.html.]

> "the application has exited and yet there are still a bunch of these
> connections open"
>
> "They are in the TIME_WAIT state which means that the connection has
> been closed on one side (ours) but we’re still waiting to see if any
> additional packets come in on it because they might have been delayed
> on the network somewhere."

Even if you're using a singleton HttpClient, it seems that some of the connections are awaiting for additional packages which leads to socket exaustion.

The solution is to change your code and use HttpClientFactory or [HttpClientFacotoryLite](https://github.com/uhaciogullari/HttpClientFactoryLite). The reason to use HttpClientFactory is that produces HttpClient instances that resuse Socket handlers from a pool of socket handlers. The handlers are recycled periodically to also take care of DNS changes. In summary, when using HttpClientFactory, HttpClient delegates work to a SocketClientHandler.

Comment: mmm HttpClientFacotory is what we used before implementing Singleton, and we had this same problem. We tested different methods with the same results.

Comment: if even with HttpClientFactory you're facing this problem, it means the current app service plan is not enough for your http requests.